# JVM failed to start "Could not reserve enough space for object"

Tags: java, jvm

Unable start java applications ending up with below error: 32 bit JVM windows

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Could not reserve enough space for object he
>   Could not create the Java virtual machine.
>   JVM exited while loading the application.

I have checked the processes and observed no processes is using jvm.
Can some one help me to solve the above error?

Comment: I would be helpful to see which parameters you're providing to the JVM on startup (the command line).

Answer (score 0):

*Could not reserve enough space for object heap* is mainly caused by providing a memory size to `-Xmx` which can not be allocated by the system.

Windows 32 bit will give you (IIRC) about 2GiB maximum memory per process, Java needs some space for its internal stuff which leaves you with around 1.4 to 1.6GiB of maximum heap.

Just try to lower the `-Xmx` parameter until it creates the VM.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible causes is that you set the minimal heap size to reserve more memory than available. set using the -Xms flag to the java command. If this flag is set make sure this amount of memory is free for use on your system.